# GStreamer- Ubuntu 16 vs Ubuntu 14

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer, pygtk, ubuntu-16.04

This is a very weird problem that I am experiencing and don't have a clue of the solution. 
I am making a GUI for a robot and I needed a video player that could exit and start up quickly. I found that PyGTK library and GStreamer

```
import os
import gst, gtk, gobject

class VideoPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect('destroy', self.on_destroy)
        self.window.set_size_request(640, 480)

        self.drawingarea = gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.drawingarea.connect('realize', self.on_drawingarea_realized)
        self.window.add(self.drawingarea)

        self.playbin = gst.element_factory_make('playbin2')
        self.playbin.set_property('uri',"file:///home/anger.ogv") #filepath

        self.sink = gst.element_factory_make('xvimagesink')
        self.sink.set_property('force-aspect-ratio', True)
        self.playbin.set_property('video-sink', self.sink)

        self.bus = self.playbin.get_bus()
        self.bus.add_signal_watch()
        self.bus.connect("message::eos", self.on_finish)

        self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

        self.window.show_all()

        self.playbin.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

    def on_finish(self, bus, message):
        self.playbin.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
        gtk.main_quit()

    def on_destroy(self, window):
        self.playbin.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
        gtk.main_quit()

    def on_drawingarea_realized(self, sender):
        self.sink.set_xwindow_id(self.drawingarea.window.xid)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    VideoPlayer()
    gtk.main()
```

I must admit that this is a code that I found on a website and it worked. I just changed the filepath. But when I switched to Ubuntu 16 from Ubuntu 14, it stopped working.
I am getting **no error and the window opens fine but the video does not play**. I have absolutely no clue. The question is **is there some change in the way gst works between Ubuntu 16 and 14?** What can be the solution?